# Using UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script to fetch a web page and resolve a server error code 500

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, internal-server-error, server-error

I want to get some listing data from YellowPages.com using Google Apps Script. Using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` in GAS (as shown below), the server throws a 500 error. However, I can successfully use `IMPORTXML()` inside a Google Sheet on the same URL and it works fine.

What explains this difference in behavior? And what can I do differently in Google Apps Script to achieve the same, desired result I'm getting from `IMPORTXML()`?

### Google Sheets [image]

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.yellowpages.com/al/accounting-services", "//div[@class='v-card']//a/@href")
```

The behavior is as expected. The result is an array of links.

### Google Apps Script [image]

Code.gs

```
const ENDPOINT = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/al/accounting-services';
const main = () => {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch( ENDPOINT, );
  const responseContentText = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log('(line 5) responseContentText\n%s', responseContentText,);
  return responseContentText;
}
```

The behavior not as expected. The result is a 500 error.

Error message:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://www.yellowpages.com returned code 500. Truncated server response: <html>
 <head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
 <body>
 <center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
 <hr><center>openresty</... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 16, file "Code")
```

Why is the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` method throwing an error and what can be done to make it behave like `IMPORTXML()`?

Comment: I'd think this website could be blocking requests made from `UrlFetchApp` somehow (I tried making the request using several other tools and it was working correctly everywhere else). Depending on your exact situation, you might want to publish your script as a web app and use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: @Iamblichus: But what could the server possibly be seeing that let's it identify `UrlFetchApp` as the source of the request? They are all unauthenticated `GET` requests, right? An IP address of a Google Server is the only thing I can think of. But then, assuming Google cycles the use of its servers, it should only get blocked for a subset of all the requests. Correct? Thoughts?

Comment: If you are still looking for the solution of this question, for example, is this 1st script useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024816/7108653 And also, about the reason of your issue, how about the experiment at the section of "Added:"?