# UrlFetchApp request fails in Menu Functions but not in Custom Functions (connecting to external REST API)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ip, binance, urlfetch

I am using the following function to connect to an external API (Binance) using a Google Apps Script to retrieve a JSON array (of market prices). This simple query url works fine in a browser (no need for API keys):

```
function getMyArray() {
  var url ="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price"; // works perfectly in browser
  var params =  {"method"  : "get",  "muteHttpExceptions":true };  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var array = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  return array;
}
```

However it's a different story when I try to run the function in Google Apps Script:

1. **Script Editor**: easy and practical to run within the script editor, but I get a `403 error` "Request blocked"
2. **Menu function**: call the function from a menu item added to spreadsheet UI => same `403 error`
3. **Custom function**: edit any cell and type `=getMyArray()` => request works and I can trace the array using Logger

Why is my simple request getting blocked when called from Menu or Script Editor, and is it possile to change that? Thanks

Comment: From your situation, I proposed a workaround as an answer. When that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `UrlFetchApp` is used by the custom function and the script editor, I think that the difference is whether IPv6 is used, while the address of IPv4 is changed every run. In this case, the results of the script editor and custom menu are the same. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. But I'm not sure whether my guess is the correct. So, in this answer, I would like to propose the following workaround.

1. Put the formula `=getMyArray()` to a cell using the script.

   - By this, the value is retrieved to the cell.
2. Retrieve the values from the cell using the script.
3. Clear the put formula.

By this flow, I think that your goal can be achieved.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this script, as a test, `=getMyArray()` is put to the cell "A1" on the active sheet and the value is retrieved from the cell. When you use this, please run the function `main()` at the script editor and custom menu. By this, the value can be retrieved to `array`.

```
function getMyArray() {
  var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price";
  var params =  {"method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  return response.getContentText();
}

// Please run this function by the script editor and the custom menu.
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  range.setFormula("=getMyArray()");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.clearContent();
  var array = JSON.parse(value);
  console.log(array)
}
```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

### Added:

The response value from `https://httpbin.org/get` is as follows.

#### Sample script for testing this:

```
function sample() {
  var url = "https://httpbin.org/get";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
  return res.getContentText();
}
```

#### Result:

Pattern 1. Script is run with the script editor.

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: ###)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=###"
  }, 
  "origin": "### IPV6 ###, ### IPV4 ###", // or "### IPV4 ###, ### IPV4 ###"
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

- When you are using IPV6, `origin` is `"### IPV6 ###, ### IPV4 ###"`. But when you are using IPV4, `origin` is `"### IPV4 ###, ### IPV4 ###"`.
- In this case, the correct value cannot be retrieved from `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price`.

Pattern 2. Script is run with the custom function.

In this case, `=sample()` is put to a cell and the value is retrieved.

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: ###)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=###"
  }, 
  "origin": "### IPV4 ###", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

- In this case, the correct value can be retrieved from `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price`.

Pattern 3. Script is run with the OnEdit event trigger.

When `UrlFetchApp` is used with the custom function, no authorization is required. But when `UrlFetchApp` is used with the OnEdit event trigger, the installable trigger is required by authorizing. I thought that this authorization might occur this issue. So I compared this.

When `UrlFetchApp` is used with the installable OnEdit event trigger, the following result is retrieved.

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: ###)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=###"
  }, 
  "origin": "### IPV4 ###", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

- This result is the same with above pattern 2.
- In this case, the correct value can be retrieved from `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price`.

#### Result:

- The headers including `User-Agent` are the same for all patterns.
- From pattern 2 and 3, it is not related to the authorization for Google side.
- When WHOIS with IPV4 is retrieved, the same result is returned.

  - When `origin` is `"### IPV4 ###, ### IPV4 ###"`, 2nd IPV4 is the Google's IP address.

From above results, the different of all patterns is whether the value of `origin` is 1 or 2.

Comment: It's a workaround for sure but I am still curious to know the exact cause of this error.

Comment: @SAAD Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When `UrlFetchApp` is used by the custom function and the script editor, I think that the difference is whether IPv6 is used, while the address of IPv4 is changed every run. In this case, the results of the script editor and custom menu are the same. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. But I'm not sure whether my guess is the correct. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: You don't have to apologize, I am already thankful for this first analysis, but I will dig deeper, and will accept the answer if it turns out to be true

Comment: @SAAD Thank you for replying. I added more information for experimental result. From them, it is found that the different for all patterns is with and without IPV6. So I think that this is the reason of this issue. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Nice. But The ip4 address is Google's server address and the ip6 address is yours. The difference is the extra address, which is not the correct syntax for "origin" header. The difference is not ip6 vs ip4. For eg, If ip6 addresses are restricted and only ip4 allowed, you'll get "###IP4 ### IP4###". The first ip4 is yours. The second one is Google's.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Oh! I'm sorry. I could notice that I had misunderstood about the IPv6. And I could understand about your comment. In this case, it seems that when there are 2 `origin` values, the issue occurs. Because when I remove my IPV6, I confirmed that the values of `origin` are 2 IPV4 addresses. I had forgot that I'm using both IPV4 and IPV6.

Comment: @TheMaster And, I could update my answer. Thank you. Could you please confirm it? By the way, it seems that when I confirm the IPV6 for `### IPV6 ###, ### IPV4 ###` again, the IP address is different from my IPV6 address, while the IPV4 for `### IPV4 ###, ### IPV4 ###` is the same with my IP address.

Comment: Tbh, I am no expert in these IP differences, but I'll accept the answer given the detailed explanations and tests you've provided