# How to change/control IP Address of URLFetch out of google script

Tags: google-apps-script, ip, urlfetch

I am working with google script.

Is there a way to control what IP Address the URLFetch call comes out with?

Is it possible with a more raw HTTP request?

Comment: AFAIK, Not possible.

Comment: Thank you. @TheMaster. Is there any info on how the IPs are assigned?   Ie. how one would need to make sure that one call has a different IP from another?   Are they assigned randomly per each call? session? other 'module'? Would two calls spaced in time get a different IP?

Comment: Randomly. The rest no one really knows. You have to test it. The only related test, I'm aware of is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024816/)