# Google Sheets: Function in script editor return different value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new with Google Sheets Script Editor. I am trying to get a function that returns how many time a word (in this case Mother) is present in a Bing website search. So I try this code:

```
function myFunction112() {
  const url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=“Not all of us can do great things. But we can do small things with great love.”";
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const numberOfOcurrencies = (html.match(/Mother/g) || []).length;
  console.log(numberOfOcurrencies);
  return numberOfOcurrencies;
}
```

The problem is that in Console it shows 18 for numberOfOcurrencies that is correct, but in my google sheet return 0. As you can see in the images below.

[Script editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOAeg.jpg)

[Google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwUZY.jpg)

I call my function myFunction112 to make sure no other function has the same name.
How can I make my function return the same value that shows in console?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you exclude all other possibilities and other answers(that may come), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024346/)  may be  a possibility.

Comment: Thanks your answer! Reading it I have decide to run my script from editor and use setValues() to update the value in Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

| Supported services | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| Cache | Works, but not particularly useful in custom functions |
| HTML | Can generate HTML, but cannot display it (rarely useful) |
| JDBC |  |
| Language |  |
| Lock | Works, but not particularly useful in custom functions |
| Maps | Can calculate directions, but not display maps |
| Properties |  |
| Spreadsheet | Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()). |
| URL Fetch |  |
| Utilities |  |
| XML |  |

[Guidelines for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#guidelines_for_custom_functions)