# Google App Script : 403 when running UrlFetchApp in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am creating an API to record Google Form responses.

I have implemented the following code in GAS and am using UrlFetchApp in GAS to run Endpoint when submitting Google Forms.

When executing UrlFetchApp, sometimes it succeeds with 200 and sometimes it fails with 403, and I would like to know why 403 is generated.
I am testing with the same Parameter of Google Form and API server side execution.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const userId = responses[0].getResponse()
  const questionnaireId = responses[1].getResponse()
  Logger.log(`userId:${userId}`);
  Logger.log(`questionnaireId:${questionnaireId}`);

  if (!isUUID(userId) || !isUUID(questionnaireId)) {
    Logger.log('Invalid UUID format.');
    return;
  }
  const baseUrl = `https://example.com`;
  const endpoint = `${baseUrl}/v1/users/${userId}/questionnaire`;
  Logger.log(`endpoint: ${endpoint}`);

  var payload = {
    "questionnaire_id": questionnaireId,
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function isUUID(str) {
  const uuidPattern = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
  return uuidPattern.test(str);
}
```

Comment: About `When executing UrlFetchApp, sometimes it succeeds with 200 and sometimes it fails with 403, and I would like to know why 403 is generated.`, in your situation, when you directly request to your API without using the OnSubmit trigger, will you obtain the same result? Because I'm worried that the values of the event object `e` might be the reason for your current issue.

Comment: Are the values of `userId` and `questionnaireId` always valid values? For example, when `if (!userId || !questionnaireId) return;` is put to just after the line of `const questionnaireId = responses[1].getResponse()`, what result will you obtain? But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, if I misunderstood the reason for your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have checked the logs at runtime and the `userId` and `questionnaireId` are displayed correctly, so I think there is no problem with `e` and `responses[1].getResponse()`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, `endpoint` and `payload` are valid values. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when you directly request your API multiple times without using the OnSubmit trigger, did you obtain the same result?

Comment: I tried running it with the `questionnaireId` and `userId` directly, but the results were the same: 200 or 403.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I tried running it with the questionnaireId and userId directly, but the results were the same: 200 or 403.`, it was found that the OnSubmit trigger might not be related to your current issue. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the specification of your API. So, as the next step, if you want to know the reason for your current issue, how about asking to the administrator of your API? And, if you want to resolve it soon, as the current workaround, how about retrying the request when 403 is returned?

Comment: For example, about the specification of your API, is some interval required to be included between requests?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

The API is implemented by us and the specification is simple to change the flag of the record to True using the passed User ID and Questionnaire ID as keys.
Also, this Endpoint is not designed to return a 403.

There is no need to the execution interval, and the request from Frontend is being handled normally.

As a workaround, I have added a process that retries 10 times with an interval of 5 seconds when a 403 occurs, but if an error occurs on the first try, all 10 times will result in an error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, as a confirmation, can you confirm the requested URLs and values from Google Apps Script with the server side, and the response values from the server? For example, I'm worried about a situation in which although the server got valid values and returned the correct value, Google Apps Script cannot correctly receive the values. First, I would like to confirm whether the reason for this issue is the Google Apps Script side or the server side.

Comment: Thank you for your frequent comments.
I have tried it with log output in the Endpoint side process, but when it succeeds, it logs, but when it is a 403, it does not log anything.
It seems that the request does not reach the API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before considering your reply, can I ask you about the details of `I tried running it with the questionnaireId and userId directly, but the results were the same: 200 or 403.` in your previous reply? In this case, when you directly requested by a curl command or other language except for Google Apps Script, what result did you obtain? Did you obtain status codes of both 200 and 403?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Using Postman, I sent 10 requests at 5 second intervals and all were successful.
I discuss this with our infrastructure staff and ask them to check the AWS WAF configuration.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Using Postman, I sent 10 requests at 5 second intervals and all were successful.`, in this case, I'm worried that the reason for the current issue might be due to the Google side. As another approach of Google Apps Script, when the request is run with the custom function, what result will you obtain? It has already been found that in the case of the request with UrlFetchApp, the request executed by the script editor is different from the request executed by the custom function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024816

Comment: But, I'm not sure whether this is related to your current issue. So, I would like to suggest testing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We removed `AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList` from the WAF rules and it now succeeds.
I think that perhaps any of the IPs used by Google is being blocked.
We need to consider the WAF rules, but this seems to be the cause.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue is resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue. And, I apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.
Your comments have allowed me to examine many possibilities.
I hope my answers will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Self Resolved.
We use AWS to build our API and when I removed `AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList` from the WAF rules, the 403 error stopped occurring.
Perhaps one of the IPs Google is using is being blocked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).